# Unable to post questions after reviewing

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I was new to StackOverflow. All I did was ask a question as other newbies. My reputation deteriorated to "3" and I was unable to post questions anymore.

After reading all the FAQ I realized the concept of StackOverflow.

So, I reviewed all my question/answers, also answered others' questions and gained a reputation of "22". I'm now able to chat. But still, I cannot **"Ask Question"** on StackOverflow.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your reputation is [11](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1445759/ecko), not 22.

There's also a [**large** amount of downvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1445759/ecko?tab=reputation) on your account. You should aim to edit your most heavily downvoted posts, to turn them into posts which attract upvotes instead.

Deleted posts **are** taken into account, so don't just delete them.

Again, [some of your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1445759/ecko?tab=questions) have downvotes. Edit those in a similar manner to get upvotes on them. Take note of [the comments on your posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039771/php-sql-autocomplete-search#comment14438256_11039771) to learn how to improve your contributions.

Comment: Okay. I'll try doing that. Sorry for the mistake. "22" was something else. Thankyou.

Comment: I tried to review as many things as possible. I managed to gain 30 reputations in the past45 minutes. Still, it isn't allowing me to Answer Questions. Does SO requires some time to update and unban? Whats your view?

Comment: @con_28 nope, ban isn't timed. The only time involved is time needed for people to see you changed, and vote. You may try to post some comments like "hello `@FriendlyUser`, I edited as you told me to, is it OK now" to notify a Friendly User that you did what he asked you to, and give him a chance to remove his downvote or provide you further assistance.